# Getting null value in property list from yaml in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, yaml

I'm working on a service and trying to read a property from a yaml file.
I'm Getting a null in some on thems even if the value is set.
This are the properties in yaml file:

```
property-combos:
  status:
    - codigo: ATIVA
      descricao: teste 1
    - codigo: CONCLUIDA
      descricao: teste 2
    - codigo: EXPIRADA
      descricao: teste 3
```

I'm reading the roperties with the following classes:

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties("property-combos")
@Validated
public class StatusProperites {

    @Valid
    protected final List<StatusDataItemProperties> status = new ArrayList<>();

    public List<StatusDataItemProperties> getStatus() {
        return status;
    }
}
```

This is the POJO

```
@Validated
public class StatusDataItemProperties {

    @NotNull
    protected String codigo;

    @NotNull
    protected String descricao;

    public String getCodigo() {
        return codigo;
    }

    public void setCodigo(String codigo) {
        this.codigo = codigo;
    }

    public String getDecricao() {
        return descricao;
    }

    public void setDecricao(String descricao) {
        this.descricao = descricao;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof StatusDataItemProperties)) return false;
        StatusDataItemProperties that = (StatusDataItemProperties) o;
        return Objects.equals(getCodigo(), that.getCodigo()) &&
                Objects.equals(getDecricao(), that.getDecricao());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(getCodigo(), getDecricao());
    }
}
```

And this is the component where i get the values from:

```
@Component
public class StatusTransacaoComponent {

 

       private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(StatusTransacaoComponent.class);
        private static final String SUCESSO = "000";
    
        @Autowired
        StatusProperites statusProperites;
    
        public List<StatusDataItemProperties> getStatusCombo(){
            return statusProperites.getStatus();
        }
    
    }
```

**Problem:** The probles is when the app is starting the properties are readed, but the values are like this:

```
codigo: ATIVA
descricao: null
```

And this happens with all of these properties

**Tried solutions:** I´ve tried to change variable and property name, but always I'm getting the null value in constant descricao.

**Question:** What could be happening and how can i resolve this,
thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have typos in getter and setter, please change to the following:

```
public String getDescricao() {
    return descricao;
}

public void setDescricao(String descricao) {
    this.descricao = descricao;
}
```

If you add this dependency to your POM

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
```

you can annotate your data class with `@Data` and skip getters/setters.

Answer (score 0):

You have code mistakes in getDecricao and setDecricao, should correct like this

```java
public String getDescricao() {
    return descricao;
}

public void setDescricao(String descricao) {
    this.descricao = descricao;
}
```